# Struts2 Jquery jqGrid beforeShowForm Example

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, struts2-jquery, struts2-jquery-plugin, struts2-jquery-grid

I'm looking for a way to use the beforeShowForm event when opening the edit dialog on a struts2-jquery grid. I want to be able to add custom fields to the edit dialog.

```
<sjg:grid
        altRows="false"
        id="gridtable"
        dataType="json"
        editurl="%{editurl}"
        filter="true"
        filterOptions="{stringResult:true}"
        gridModel="gridModel"
        height="600"
        href="%{remoteurl}"         
        loadonce="true"
        navigator="true"
        navigatorAdd="%{editPermission}"
        navigatorAddOptions="{reloadAfterSubmit:true,addCaption:'Add Record'}" 
        navigatorDelete="false"
        navigatorEdit="%{editPermission}"
        navigatorRefresh="true"
        navigatorSearch="false"
        onCompleteTopics="loadComplete"
        onSelectRowTopics="rowselect"
        pager="true"
        pagerButtons="true"
        rowList="25,50,100"
        rowNum="25"
        rownumbers="true"
    >
```

However, I'm having issues understanding how to utilize the beforeShowForm event with the sjg tag. I've search for the solution for days, but all of them seem to be only when using regular jqGrid and not the sjg tag specifically. Most examples seem to reference the jqGrid wiki, but again I don't understand the way to access that event. Can someone please give me an example of assigning a function to beforeShowForm on the edit button within the sjg tag?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use struts2 myself. I suppose that the id of the grid is `"gridtable"`. I suggest you to use **jQuery events instead of callbacks**. You need just to use [jQuery.bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/). The most callbacks have the corresponding jQuery events which exist in jqGrid starting with version 4.3.2. The most difference of the usage of jQuery events is adding of additional first parameter which gives you not so much information in our case. You can use for example

```
$("#gridtable").bind("jqGridAddEditBeforeShowForm", function (e, $form, oper) {
    alert("In jqGridAddEditBeforeShowForm");
});
```

In the way you can transform the most other solutions which you will find in the usage of jQuery events.

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance as I ask questions to understand your answer. I understand the concept of binding an event to a function. However, from your example if I put '.bind("beforeShowForm",...' then it doesn't show the alert. Is the beforeShowForm an event on the grid, or an event on the dialog?

Comment: I understand now, I must have the code above AFTER the loadComplete event fires.
      
 `$.subscribe('loadComplete', function(event, data) {
  $("#gridtable").bind("jqGridAddEditBeforeShowForm", function (e, $form, oper) {
   alert("In jqGridAddEditBeforeShowForm");
  }); 
 })`

Comment: For future reference how do I find that jqGridAddEditAfterShowForm or jqGridAddEditBeforeShowForm is an event? I don't see those events listed in any of the jqGrid documentation.

Comment: @user3420328: Look at [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_triggered_events_new_in_v4.3.2). Depend on version of jqGrid which you use there are different number of events, but every new version contains more and more events. By the way if `<table ud="gridtable"></table>` exist you can already do binding `$("#gridtable").bind("jqGridAddEditBeforeShowForm", ...);` **even before the grid is created and before the pager with navigator bar is created.

Comment: @user3420328: instead of `$.subscribe('loadComplete',...)` you can use `$("#gridtable").bind("jqGridLoadComplete", function(event, data) { ...});` The only thing where you should be careful with events: the `<table ud="gridtable"></table>` should exist. So you should make binding inside of `$(function () {...});` (document.ready). If the `<table>` will be created and placed on the page *dynamically* the you should start binding after the `<table>` is placed on the HTML page.

Comment: That's fantastic information, thank Oleg. The struts2-jquery plugin v3.7.1 uses jqgrid v4.6.0, so it should have all the events listed in that documentation. Thanks again for the help and the useful suggestions.

Comment: @user3420328: You are welcome! I'm glad that I could help you.